# SVG not displayed with android 6 and cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, svg

My tablet with android 6 doesn't show svg image, there is a grey image instead. My application is made with cordova and vuejs.

I've try to launch my application with a tablette with android 7 and an other with android 9 and it's working perfectly. I think the problem is because of the android webview...

If someone has the solution of my problem or has an other opinion.

Thank you.

Comment: I have an Android 6.0.1 device and no problems with SVGs

Comment: Mine is Android 6.0